Excel - Auto increment ID row column cell on insert
Can this scenario be achieved in Excel so I get automatic ID column increment every time new row is inserted? (no matter in which place - at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of sheet):

There is a cell in excel (lets call it max_value) which holds integer value;
There is a column (column A) which holds IDs (all of these ids will be <= max_value);
After user inserts new row, no matter in which place, max_value gets first incremented by 1, and then column A in that new row is populated with max_value.


You can achieve this with VBA. Please, post the code you've tried, where are you stuck and what errors are you getting. Anyways, if you really need to handle auto ID increment Excel clearly is not the best option for that. Consider using other options like Access or SQL and combine them with Excel.

Do you want that to be done automatically after inserting a row/rows? What about the case of inserting more than a row? To increment each row starting with the above one? How to proceed in case of row(s) deletion? Should row deletion not be allowed?

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns before i even try I want to know if it is possible, if yes I will try to provide some code. Would like to stay with excel as convincing others to use different tool may be painful and everyone knows excel =)

@FaneDuru yes automatically, I can restrict users to add 1 row at a time to make things easier. Row deletion should be allowed, max_value will be stored in separate cell for new rows anyway

There is no any event supplied by Microsoft to be triggered by row(s) deletion. But worksheet Change event I think can be used to do it. Then, when I asked about row deletion I did not have in mind deletion of the row containing max_value... I meant, don't you need any correlation between the existing rows (with data) and that max_value number? I mean, if there is a total of 10 rows and a deletion of all of them, will make the max looking strange. What do you have in mind related to restricting row insertion at only one? Instructing them verbally, or creating code to not allow that?

To be on the safe side (problem of detecting row insert/delete), seems good to make two buttons for insert and delete and use the activecell position as reference of the insertion.

@FaneDuru no need for correlation, I just need to have unique numeric values, there can be gaps etc, basically all I need is described in the question. Regarding restricting users from inserting multiple rows - verbally, so it is not a part of my requirements regarding the solution. No need to perform any action on row delete, only on row insertion.

If ID is always increased by 1 then: Use a table (insert > table) with formula in column A =ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers]). Formula for max value: =MAX(Table1[ID])

To do what you want, a marker string is necessary to be placed in column A:A, in a row supposed to be outside the range where the rows will be inserted. So write "Marker" in the respective cell.
In another sheet ("Sheet2") in the  following example, write the initial max_value. It would be good that this sheet to be hidden, to not change the reference value by mistake
Please, copy the next code in the sheet to be processed (where to increment in A:A column) code module:
Option Explicit

Private markerRowNo As Long                  'the Marker row when a whole row is selected
Private rngMark As Range                     'the range where the Marker is (to be found)
Private Const shMaxName As String = "Sheet2" 'the sheet name where the max row is kept (in "A1")
Private max_value As Long                    'the reference value to be incremented

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Columns.Count = Me.Columns.Count Then
     If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then 'if inserted more than a row:
        Application.EnableEvents = False
         markerRowNo = 0: Application.Undo 'reverse the rows insertion
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        MsgBox "Not allowed to insert more than a row at a time!", vbInformation, "No more than one row": Exit Sub
     End If
     Set rngMark = Me.Columns(1).Find(what:="Marker", After:=Me.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
     If rngMark.Row > markerRowNo Then   'if the row where the maker exists is bigger then the previous => insertion
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'to avoid triggering the event continuously
         max_value = Worksheets(shMaxName).Range("A1").Value
         Target.Cells(1).Value = max_value + 1 'place the necessary value in A:A
         Worksheets(shMaxName).Range("A1").Value = max_value + 1 'adapt the maximum row reference
        Application.EnableEvents = True
     End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Target.Columns.Count = Me.Columns.Count Then 'if a whole row has been selected
        'find the marker cell:
        Set rngMark = Me.Columns(1).Find(what:="Marker", After:=Me.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        markerRowNo = rngMark.Row                    'update the markerRowNo variable
     End If
End Sub

The first triggered event is SelectionChange which, in case of a whole row selection, memorizes the "Marker" row number.
The second triggered event is Change, which determines if a whole row has been inserted, write in A:A the incremented row number and also increment the reference cell.
This last event takes care of the multiple rows insertion. In such a case it UnDo insertion and send a relevant message...
Please, send some feedback after testing it. I tried commenting all the code lines, but if still something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

@sjanisz Please, download a testing workbook form here and play with it. I used it to test the above code. I never needed such an events combinations but I tried this now...

I am on this, it works like supposed in case of insert but I will want to remove feature that when row is removed then row below id is replaced by new value, I will want this to stay as it was before

@sjanisz Ups... It is a mistake there and I did not test it as it should after I tried using your existing max_value variable. By mistake I also copied it in the SelectionChange event. It must be replaced with markerRowNo. I will do it immediately. Did it! Without that, the code cannot distinguish between insertion or deletion... And it did that when I designed it and tested.

@sjanisz You can test that on the updated testing workbook which can be downloaded from -here...
